# How to use setClob method in jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc

I need to insert a large string as clob into a table. I am using setClob method of PreparedStatement. But the values are not getting inserted into the database table. Can anyone tell me how I can insert the string into the table using setClob method?

I'm using the method as follows:

pstmt.setClob(0, clob);

But the program can't execute the statements from this line. It comes out of the loop and stops again at the same line and so on...
I'm in a dilemma how to use Clob Object to achieve this.

Please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What database are you inserting the value to? For example for Oracle back-end, preparedStatement methods have 4k limitation on CLOB.

You could use:

```
Clob clob = ...
String chuck = clob.getSubString(1,10);
clob.setString(1,chuck);
```

To verify that the size is not the issue here.

Comment: I'm using Oracle. How do we initialize Clob object?
I used clob.setString to set the value and then stmt.setClob() to set the clob for a column. But it did not work.

Comment: As I understand oracle prefers, that you write an empty clob with empty_clob() procedure, into the table, then select it and write to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using WebLogic and Oracle.
I found the solution in the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb11jav.htm under the section "Loading a Large XML Document into the Database with JDBC"

The only problem I had with this was that the CLOB.createTemporary required an OracleConnection, but my connection object was of type $ProxyXX which I could not cast to OracleConnection without getting a ClassCastException. 
Solved it buy using conn.getMetaData().getConnection() that got me a T4CConnection which I could cast to OracleConnection.